# Problems assigning variables to SQLite Tuples

Tags: python, database, sqlite

First off, I apologize if this seems elementary, I am fairly new to python and ***very*** new to SQlite. I also apologize for the wall of text, but I have gotten so much help from this site, that maybe someone else can learn from this issue as well.

I have one SQLite database `levelData.db`with two tables called `Counters_Daily` & `Counters_Total`. Each table has three rows corresponding to data from things like water usage, so the daily table has a row called `dailyWater` and the total table has it's own row called `totalWater` I am trying to write a script which, at the end of the day will take the data that is in the `Counters_Daily` and add them to the `Counters_Total`.

I've tried wrapping my head around this and the most elementary solution I can come up with is to convert the data back to variables so that I can covert them and then replace them in the database. This has worked for me to get data into the database to start with. Here is an example of my working code:

```
def waterCounter(waterUsed):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('levelData.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute ('SELECT * FROM Counters_Daily')
    originalData = int(c.fetchone()[1])
    updatedData = originalData + waterUsed
    c.execute ("UPDATE Counters_Daily SET DailyWater = (?)", (updatedData,))
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```

My problem then becomes when I try to update the `Counters_Total` database. As I mentioned, I want to add the daily data to the total data. So I figured I would extract the data and assign it to a variable (similar to the script above), but I'm having a problem unpacking those tuples and this is where my problem comes in. Here is my code:

```
def showData():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('levelData.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    print "getting started"
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM Counters_Total')
    totalCounters = c.fetchall() #Assigns the list to a variable
    totalData = tuple(totalCounters) #Converts the list to tuples
    print "totalCounters:"
    print totalCounters
    print type(totalCounters)
    print "TotalData:"
    print totalData
    print type(totalData)
    (totalWater, totalLight, totalAir) = totalData #Assigns variables to each one of the tuples
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```

And this is the output I get:

```
getting started
totalCounters:
[(50.0, 51.0, 52.0)]
<type 'list'>
TotalData:
((50.0, 51.0, 52.0),)
<type 'tuple'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "databaseWorking.py", line 129, in <module>
    showData()
  File "databaseWorking.py", line 47, in showData
    (totalWater, totalLight, totalAir) = totalData
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

What is interesting to me is that it looks like the tuple conversion is where things are going awry because it lists the tuples as `((50.0, 51.0, 52.0),)` and I have no idea why there is an extra comma at the end. Anyway, that is where I am stuck. I appreciate any help or advice you can recommend.

**EDIT**

Thank you to both @Setop and @timgeb for their help and explanations. I was able to use this code and now everything is copacetic:

```
def showData2():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('levelData.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    print "getting started"
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM Counters_Total')
    totalCounters = c.fetchall() #Assigns the list to a variable
    (totalWater, totalLight, totalAir) = tuple(totalCounters[0])
    print "totalCounters:"
    print totalCounters
    print type(totalCounters)
    print "totalWater:"
    print totalWater
    print "totalLight:"
    print totalLight
    print "totalWater:"
    print totalAir
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchall` returns a list of tuples, something that looks like

```
totalCounters = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

When you do `totalData = tuple(totalCounters)` you do not convert the list to tuple**S**, you convert *the* list to *a* tuple (and unless you want to modify that datastructure, you are not really changing much by doing that):

```
>>> totalData = tuple(totalCounters)
>>> totalData
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))
```

So now you have a tuple of tuples. Your actual example `((50.0, 51.0, 52.0),)` is similar, but the outer tuple only contains one element - so you have a tuple containing a single tuple.

When you do `var1, var2, var3 = some_iterable` Python expects an iterable with three elements on the right hand side and assigns the names `var1`, `var2` and `var3` to the first, second and third element respectively.

The problem is that `((50.0, 51.0, 52.0),)` only has one element, the tuple `(50.0, 51.0, 52.0)` and that's why you get your error.

You either need to choose a specific three-element tuple from your tuple/list of tuples for unpacking

```
>>> a, b, c = totalData[0]
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
```

or loop over the tuples (only useful if you can have more than one tuple in your iterable) and unpack each of them like this:

```
>>> for a, b, c in totalData:
...     print a, b, c
... 
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Lastly, if you are using Python 3, there's a handy feature called extended iterable unpacking that lets you use a wildcard name that catches all "remaining" elements - which is useful if you don't know how many elements the iterable you want to unpack contains. Demo:

```
>>> first, *middle, last = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> first
1
>>> middle
[2, 3, 4]
>>> last
5
>>> 
>>> head, *tail = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> head
1
>>> tail
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This was very thorough, thank you! @Setop helped me with a similar code, but your explanation of  "list of tuples" is what finally made it click in my head. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

"totalCounters" is an list.
so you have to pick up an element.
like `totalData = tuple(totalCounters[0])`

Comment: You're incredible, thank you! My only question is what does the `[0]` mean? My understanding of the `[x]` code was that would indicate the first data entry in the list. Does that mean that the list is one giant tuple. I know that sounds stupid, I'm just trying to understand it better. Thank you again!

Comment: `fetchall` returns a list if tuples. In your case, a list of only one tuple because your query returns only one record. `[0]` means the first element of a list. In that case a tuple. The tuple. After that you can use list/tuple comprehension to assign content to variable.