# Sqlite3 assign fetched record into variables

Tags: python, sqlite

I have researched this topic online but have yet to find a solution to my problem. The closest was a question on this website:

[Problems assigning variables to SQLite Tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079011/problems-assigning-variables-to-sqlite-tuples)

However with this it converts it using integer as it uses numbers, however this could not be done with my data.

This is my current code which is based upon that previous question:

```
   def View_Trainer_Record(self, index):
            self.cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Trainers WHERE rowid=?', (index+1,))

            global Record
            Record = self.cur.fetchone()
            (Name, TrainerID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Password) = tuple(Record[0])
            print ("Record")
            print (Record)
            print ("Name")
            print (Name)
            print ("TrainerID")
            print (TrainerID)
            print ("Postcode")
            print (Postcode)
            print ("Age")
            print (Age)
            print ("Gender")
            print (Gender)
            print ("Password")
            print (Password)
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

The question I am asking is how could I split up each piece in this fetched record into individual variables to call later in another class.

Comment: Try `tuple(Record)`, not Record[0], which will select the first column of your select.

Comment: Even better with `Name, TrainerID, Postcode, Age, Gender, Password = Record`

Comment: Thanks I removed the [0] and it printed

Comment: Why is your Record global? You can return the values with a `return Record`

Comment: Unpacking values from a `tuple` or from a `list` is about the same as they are both iterables.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you advice. I made Record global as I need it to print in a different class and I am quite new to coding so this is the method I am aware of.